# can anyone post their windows 7 UILanguages\en-US key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, language

I am having issues getting Windows 7 to change my system language to English. I followed the normal process but it's not completely changing it.
I want to verify if my

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages\en-US]
```

key is set correctly. Current values are:

```
"LCID"=dword:00000409
"Type"=dword:00000091
```

can anyone with Windows 7 with english as the system language post their said key values?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've got these.

[image]

Why don't you change it from the usual way? Download it from Windows Update and set your language at Control Panel -> Region and language -> Keyboard and Languages tab.

(WARN: you can only change language in certain editions of Windows 7 (and Vista))

Pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you tell us more, we'll help more. :)

Comment: wow. thanks for all the info. the problem was that no matter what i did (including the steps shown in your screen shots), i could not uninstall spanish as a display language. it was still defined as the "system language" when i clicked on "Uninstall display languages". i removed the spanish registry key from UILanguages and then i was able to uninstall it. if others have the same experience, i will make this the official answer.  
thanks